# Spring Aggregation Framework and MongoDB version 3.6

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework

We have written several Spring Data Mongo Aggregation queries in our Spring Boot application (version 1.5.3). When we wrote the aggregations we were using MongoDB version 3.4. Everything worked fine. When we upgraded to MongoDB version 3.6 the aggregations no longer worked.
 The following error occurs: "com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 9: 'The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument'".

We added the explain argument. There is no longer an exception, but the mappedResults collection is now empty. The raw results are present.

Here is the relevant section of code:

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation
    .newAggregation(matchOperation, unwindOperation, groupOperation, projectionOperation,
        sortOperation, groupOperationPush, sortOperationNext)
    .withOptions(Aggregation.newAggregationOptions().allowDiskUse(true).build());

AggregationResults<OurDomainClass> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "ourCollection", OurDomainClass.class);


return results.getMappedResults();
```

I've read that as of Spring Data MongoDB version 2.1, Spring has adapted to MongoDB version 3.6. However, at Maven Central the version of Spring Data MongoDB only goes as far as 2.07.

Is there a workaround we can apply to our aggregation code, maybe somehow mapping the raw results manually to our domain class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stable versions are available in the maven central while for the others, (ie at the time of writing version 2.1) you need to specify the repository in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

see [Spring-data-mongodb quickstart](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/#quick-start)

maybe your aggregation query is not valid/behaving in a different way, to check you can enable the `mongotemplate` logging and check the generated aggregation query that you can copy/paste in the mongo console to verify it. `logback.xml` snippet:

```
<logger name="org.springframework.data.mongodb" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate" level="DEBUG"/>
```